# How do I know in which countries is my app available through App Store?

Tags: ios, localization, internationalization, app-store, app-store-connect

Each country's AppStore restricts apps by language. If I have my app's descriptions in languages A, B and C, how do I know in which countries it will become available? There seems to be no easy way of knowing this other than checking App Stores for each of the 200 countries one by one, unless I'm missing something of course.

Additionally, if I have an English description, will my app be available in countries that are restricted to British, Australian and other variations of English?

Answer (score 4):

You can also check the availability of the application published on apple store connect, by opening the edit option for the availability of regions and countries.
The steps are as follows:

1. Open app info on the **App Store Connect**,
2. In the **General** tab select the **Pricing and Availability** option,
3. Under the **Availability** section next to **All Countries or regions selected**, click **Edit**,
4. The **Country or Region Availability** window opens. Here you can see and select the countries and regions in which the application may be available.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

There is no such restriction per language (if there is, I would be interested about any documentation respecting that restriction).

What happens is: if you have languages A, B & C, then you need to have one that is the main language, let's say it's B. And let's say A is English, B is Portuguese and C is Spanish.

Any country that has English as their language (e.g. Australia, USA) will have A language.

Any country that has Spanish as their language (e.g. Ecuador, Spain) will have C language.

Any other country will show Portuguese language in the description.

See screenshot, where it states "Principal" that is the main language: [image]

Comment: Hi mojuba, would you consider marking my answer as correct or explain a bit more about what extra info you need / anything that needs clarification? Thanks!

Comment: Try tagging @mojuba as such

Comment: Thanks @jdero ! The post owner is always notified, so in this case it's not necessary, but that's a good one!

Comment: @Injuanj TIL how stackoverflow *really* work :D Follow up question for your answer: I  was personally trying to find the way to change the app's available location, not necessarily the language. But is there some overlap between language and location? If I select the English language but cancel all the English-speaking countries from the list, and only enable in a country like Hungary (~20% English speaking). How does Apple handle this?

Comment: Easy one @jdero :) In the case you mentioned, the app is available to everyone in Hungary. Language availability never restricts the usage in any country. Language availability only affects in a way that, in case the user has a language the app supports, then the app will use that language. Otherwise, the app will use its default language.

Comment: That makes sense -@lnjuanj - it's really just a matter of in app support. Very cool, thanks!